# Find all functions satisfying the functional equation $ xf(x) + f(1-x) = x^3 - x $

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations

> Find all functions, for all real x, that satisfy the following functional equation:
>
> $$ xf(x) + f(1-x) = x^3 - x $$

Comment: I think $x=1-u$ would help.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, a reasonable thing to do is just plug in some values for $x$.

Comment: Sorry if this may sound a bit naive, but if I don't know what the function is then how would I sub in values?

Comment: When $x = 0$ then $(0)f(0)+f(1)=0^3-0\implies f(1) = 0$ is the solution.  Try to build off of that.

Comment: For example, let $x=0$. Then, $f(1) = 0$. Let $x=1$, then what?

Comment: Wouldn't that be f(1) + f(0) = 0 still? @aduh

Answer (score 5):

We have 
\begin{align*}
xf(x) + f(1-x) &= x^3-x\\
(1-x)f(1-x) + f(1-(1-x)) &= (1-x)^3 - (1-x)
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
f(x) + (1-x)f(1-x)  = (1-x)^3 - (1-x)
\end{align*}
Multiplying the first equation by $1-x$ and subtracting from the third equation, we get
\begin{align*}
(x(1-x) - 1)f(x) &= (x^3-x)(1-x) - (1-x)^3 + (1-x)\\
(-x^2+x-1)f(x) &= x^3-x - x^4 + x^2 - (1-3x+3x^2-x^3) + 1-x \\
&= -x^4 + 2x^3-2x^2 +x 
\end{align*}
Hence 
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{-x^4 + 2x^3-2x^2 +x }{-x^2+x-1} = x^2 - x = x(x-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: What do you mean by 'eliminate'?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: For completeness, it should be added that the result needs be verified to satisfy the given equation (which it does, indeed, in this case) because the entire derivation is based on the implicit assumption that such $f(x)$ exists, but that assumption has not been otherwise proved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution; it is indeed very elegant and thought-out. Does this mean that only one such function exists for this problem?

Comment: Yes. There is only one such function.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, we need to verify that the obtained $f$ satisfies the given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in $x=1$ and $x=0$ in the given relation to get $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and plug in $x=1/2$ to get $f(1/2)=-1/4$. Apply Lagrange's formula for interpolation:

$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-1/2)}{(0-1)(0-1/2)}.f(0)+\frac{(x-0)(x-1/2)}{(1-0)(1-1/2)}.f(1)+\frac{(x-0)(x-1)}{(1/2-0)(1/2-1)}.f(1/2)=x(x-1)$

Comment: How do we know that $f$ must be a polynomial so that we can apply Lagrange's formula?